# INT AND INT - what is it doing when I use AND in between two variables?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim aTest As Int64 = 4 And 1 = 0
Dim aTest As Int64 = 4 And 2 = 0
Dim aTest As Int64 = 4 And 3 = 0
Dim aTest As Int64 = 4 And 4 = 4
Dim aTest As Int64 = 4 And 5 = 4
Dim aTest As Int64 = 4 And 6 = 4
```

What is the purpose of doing AND in between two variables like that? How come the values turn out to be the way they are?

Never encountered this before.

Comment: [bitwise binary and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of the file to get insight.  The Boolean to Integer conversion is the one that trips you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it is saying is

```
0100     0100    0100    0100
0001     0010    0011    0100
----     ----    ----    ----
0000     0000    0000    0100


0100
0101
----
0100
```

Note that the result is only a one if the corresponding bits in both numbers are ones.

Comment: I think you mean that the result is only a one if the corresponding bits in both numbers *are ones*.